# Is there any developer console sort of feature available to check & preview salesforce marketing cloud sql queries?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions, sql

In marketing cloud while running a sql query, to check results I have to create a data extension and store results into it. I want to know if there is any alternative available through which we can preview the results before saving it into any data extension. 
Debugging query using data extension is very lengthy & time consuming process. Also even if I want to get an idea of contact volume for a specific logic, I have to create a data extension first and then store it in the same.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no solution outside running the query inside third party SQL software like MySQL or MS SQL Server.

I know it is on SFMC's 'to do' list to offer this feature, but it does not exist yet and no specific implementation time has been officially announced.